# Change element index[0] from a list (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a list as a value of a cell in my pandas dataframe. I need to add a white space in front of the value of the first element of the list and add ' and' to the last value.

If it were written as a regular list not in Pandas or dataframe it would look like this:

```
# add a space before the first element
list[0] = ' ' + list[0]

# add 'and' for the last element
list[-1] = 'and' + list[-1]
```

But now that list is inside a df. Like this.

```
  col_A
0   [abc, abc, abc, abc]
1   [abc, abc, abc, abc]
3   [abc, abc, abc, abc]
```

So I think I need to use lambda, but I'm not sure..
This is what I have tried and it didn't work:

```
df['col_a'].apply(lambda x: ' ' + x[0])
```

The return error was:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code works for me - can you print `df.dtypes`?

Comment: also it might be easier to create deal with numpy arrays, `df['colA'] = [[' ' + a[0]] + a[1:-1] + [a[-1] + ' and']  for a in df['col_A'].values]` but could you create a sample output based on your input ?

Comment: @Manakin dtypes is an object. I've not used NumPy before, so I'll look into it.

Comment: That's your issue you have a string object not a proper list. does the above snippet work ?

Comment: @Manakin That worked! thank you!